# Set Read Permissions to logged in AD User

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, active-directory, read-only, icacls

i would like to set Read Only Permissions to a folder i created with a startup script:
md D:\Projects\%USERNAME%

Only the logged in AD User should have Read Permissions on this Folder.

I tried it with:
Icacls D:\Projects\%USERNAME% /t /c /g "%userdoamin%\%USERNAME%:r

But all AD Users get Read Permissions to this folder when they log into this PC.

Comment: yes, i need this as a startup skript because it´s for a computer lab with 25 pcs.

Comment: Just by the way, "Read Only Permission" usually means that a user (or some users) have permission to read something but not to write to it. You're talking about a situation where one user has full access to something and everybody else has none. If you use the phrase "read only permission", you risk confusing people.

Comment: You are right. Is it possbile to give the logged on AD Account R/W Permissions only on his folder that is created at login?

Comment: It certainly should be. I’m not very knowledgeable about either Windows 10 or AD, but see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1222236/354511) for some pointers on how to restrict permissions (on Windows 7). (Unfortunately, that thread is GUI-centric; if you have trouble finding the equivalent CLI-based (scriptable) commands, ask a new question, linking to this question and that one, and stating what you’ve tried, what you’ve learned, where you’re stuck and why.) The key is to withdraw permissions for all-inclusive groups like “Everyone”, “Users” and “Authenticated Users”.